# create service in NSIS with binpath in quotes

Tags: nsis

Up to today, I was using the follwing code in .nsi file to create a service:

```
nsExec::Exec 'SC CREATE "MyService" binpath= "$APPDATA\My App Folder\service\SService.exe" start="auto"'
nsExec::Exec 'sc description "MyService" "Starts The Service"'
```

It worked great, but as of today the service created cannot be started with the error: `error 193 0xc1`, or in other words, the path to service is incorrect. I opened registry Editor `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MyService` and changed `C:\ProgramData\My App Folder\service\SService.exe` to `"C:\ProgramData\My App Folder\service\SService.exe"` (added quotes) and it started working again.

The question is, how can I create a binpath with `""` around it? I tried

```
 nsExec::Exec 'SC CREATE "MyService" binpath= "$\"$APPDATA\My App Folder\service\SService.exe$\""
```

but the service is never created. What is the correct syntax to create a binpath with `""` around it in NSIS? If you have any idea, why windows suddenly decided that it wont accept my path without the `""`, please share that knowledge as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with NSIS, you are simply not using the correct syntax for sc.exe. sc.exe probably uses the [MSVC rules for command line parsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/17w5ykft(v=vs.85)) which means you must use `\"`.

```
nsExec::Exec '"$sysdir\sc.exe" CREATE "MyService" binpath= "\"$APPDATA\My App Folder\service\SService.exe\"" start= auto'
Pop $0 ; Exit code
```